# Does anyone know of any flashes that would work on an old Konica FP-1?

Tags: flash, film, konica

My mum recently gave me an old Konica FP-1 Program which she got in the 80s. I'm in by no means a professional or even an amateur really, but I was wondering if anyone could point me in the direction of a of a flash that might work for the camera. There is a hot shoe on the top so i therefore assumed there would be some compatible flash but was not able to find any information online on the exact flash units which are compatible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want an automatic "dedicated" flash, or will a manual flash be acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find a Konica flash for it on eBay. The  [FP-1 User Manual](https://www.butkus.org/chinon/konica/konica_fp-1/konica_fp-1.pdf) says the Konica X-18, X-24, and X-36 are recommended.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: @KobyAlexander, I just read the manual. Any flash can be used, but one has to choose the aperture on the lens manually according to a distance table, which is typically found on the back of the flash.